# How to join values in comma seprated string on checkbox checked Angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am passing values on checkbox chnages event in api.

I want to pass comma seprated values in URL on checkbox change like below example.

code=ABC,DEF,RED

and remove values on checkbox unchecked event like below example
code=ABC,DEF

Can any one help me to do this.

Below is my code

```
onChange(event, Code) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.newCode = Code;
    } else {
      this.newCode = '';
    }    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution could be.

**in component.ts file**

```
code: string;
selectedValues = [];

selectCheckBox(evt, val) {
  const status = evt.target.checked;

  if (status) {
    this.selectedValues.push(val)
  } else {
    this.selectedValues = this.selectedValues.filter((v) => v!==val)
  }

  this.code = this.selectedValues.join(',')
}

onSubmit() {
  let url = 'api.example.com/';
  url = `${url}/&code=${this.code}`;

  console.log(url);

  // write you logic call api etc
}
```

**In template**

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="chbx1" value="AB" (change)="selectCheckBox($event, 'AB')"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="chbx2" value="CD" (change)="selectCheckBox($event, 'BC')"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="chbx3" value="ED" (change)="selectCheckBox($event, 'CD')"></li>
</ul>

<button type="button" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhwge2)

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: @saurabh you can upvote answer it will help other mates, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array called `codeArray` to perform this action. Check the code below.

```js
let codeArray = []

onChange(event, Code) {
        if (event.checked) {
          this.codeArray.push(Code)
          this.newCode = codeArray.join(",");
        } else {
          let index = this.codeArray.indexOf(Code)
          this.codeArray.splice(index,1)
          this.newCode = codeArray.join(",");
        }    
}
```

Finally, your URL will be something like this

```
let URL = `${URL}&code=${this.newCode}`
```